# How do I get passed parameter id through fluxible router in my component?

Tags: reactjs, fluxible

I have the following route config.
dynamicPost: {
    path: '/posts/:postId',
    method: 'get',
    page: 'Post',
    title: 'Post',
    handler: SinglePost
}
How do i get post id in my Component ?

Comment: you can get it in the component using props.currentRoute.params.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
props.currentRoute.params.postId
```